# log4j different log format for different marker

Tags: logging, log4j2

I've a requirement to have different log format for different markers.Both log belong to same log level(error) and would be logged in same file.
Can anyone tell me what should be the ideal way to do this. Logger in use is log4j.

Only solution I have right now is to use different appender to get different formats. Does this has any side effect that I'm not aware of?

```
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile1" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">

            <MarkerFilter marker="MARKERONE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile2" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
            <MarkerFilter marker="MARKERTWO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>

            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile1"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile2"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a single Appender and use a PatternSelector.  See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#Pattern_Selectors. The MarkerPatternSelector does exactly what you want.

Comment: worked like a charm! @ankit why haven't you accepted this answer?